# How do I reference a field name that contains a dot in underscore template?

Tags: underscore.js-templating

I have the data object like this:

```
var data = {};
data['T.Name'] = 'World';
```

I would like to execute this template:

```
_.template('Hello <%= T.Name %>!', data)
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: T is not defined
```

I understand that underscore tries to take T object with the Name property. But I need to make it work with 'T.Name', because I have no chance to change the data format. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

_.template('Hello <%= data["T.Name"] %>!', data)

Comment: @ Alfabravo what exactly did you modify?